# Adapt the Promise returned in my angular factory

Tags: angularjs

My `getData` factory is returning a list of people objects from a .json file.

```
.factory('people', ['$q', function($q) {
    function getData() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();            
        if (event.type == 'exception') { 
            //deferred.reject(result);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(require('../../../mocks/people.json'));
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var that = {
        getData: getData
    };        
    return that;
}]);
```

In my component, I'm outputting this to the console in my browser, as you can see I have to drill down into the Promise to find the values.

[image]

Am I missing a step in my factory? I'd like to return just the data contained in my json file, I'd like to avoid doing somthing like than doing something like `console.log(Promise.$$state.value)` in my component if possible.

I'm returning the angular Promise, do I need to adapt that in some way to just see the data?

Comment: What it shows if you do `Promise.then(function(response){console.log(response)});` in your controller??

Comment: you should be resolving your promise: `people.getData().then((res)=>{console.log(res)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve your promise like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('people', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout) {
  return that = {
    getData: function getData() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();            
      if (event.type == 'exception') { 
        //deferred.reject(result);
      } else {
        $timeout(function () {
          deferred.resolve({
            'some': 'Data'
          });
        }, 500);
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function(people) {
  people.getData().then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
});
```

**> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nfp3fyt/)**